# Inserir mais valores dentro de uma variável

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
            var $e = $(e.currentTarget);
            var eData = $e.data();

            var personagem = this.model.get('personagens').get({'id': eData.personagemId});

            var candidatos = personagem.get('candidatos');
```

Eu preciso colocar mais um atributo do backbonemodel personagem dentro da variável candidatos sem alterar os valores que já estão lá, já tentei utilizar o get novamente, porem ele sobrescreve os valores que já existem dentro da variavel, existe algum meio de inserir mais um valor dentro do var candidatos sem alterar os valores que já estão nele?

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e nos diga de onde e/ou em qual formato os dados que você obtém (provavelmente por esse método *get*) vêm/estão e onde exatamente você quer adicionar (num array, num *hash table*, numa variável simples...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que entendi do seu problema voce deveria definir sua variavel candidatos como um array!

aqui tem explicação de como funciona e exemplos!

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

metodo push
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp

metodos push e unshift
http://www.tiexpert.net/programacao/web/javascript/push-unshift-inserir-elemento-array.php

Comment: Obrigado Paulo, utilizei o push e funcionou da maneira que eu precisava.

Comment: que bom Wilson, é sempre bom poder ajudar!